# Plot a shape using X,Y points

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a chart in D3 that takes in around 200 x/y points.   I can get the data into D3 no problem.  The challenge is constructing the chart.

These points if plotted as a scatter chart with smoothed lines and no points displayed make up an ellipse.

What is the best D3 construct to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use D3's [line generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line), `d3.svg.line()`. There's more information at [Dashing D3.js](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js).